Why do we say class of NP problems instead of setof NP problem?
In mathematics (at least in a naive sense); there is no concrete distinction between the words class and set. However due to some logical reasons(power set and so on...) we make statements like the class of all sets instead of set of all sets; I was wondering if there is any particular reason as to why we say class of NP problems instead of set of NP problems ?

We do say "set of all subsets" for the power set.

We also say "equivalence class", "homotopy class", etc. The sense of "class" here is as in "classify"; it is slightly more specific than "set" (i.e. it is meaning 1 here, not meaning 13).

It is classified separately from the class of $P$ problems.

@AnuradhaN. I agree with with your comment; deciding whether a problem is in NP but not in P requires the classification via a reduction to another problem with known complexity or the construction of an efficient algorithm that solves the problem, thus demonstrating that it is in P

@ManfredWeis I took the cue from the answer posted (above) by Naim Favier.
